# git shortcut to stage changes from different directory

Tags: git, version-control

Considering a git-repository in the directory **my_dir**, I have

- a subdirectory with *testdata* at **my_dir/path/to/my/testdata**
- a subdirectory with *source code* at **my_dir/a/different/path/to/my/sourcecode**

If I modify sourcecode using my IDE, but want to commit these changes via terminal from my *testdata* directory, I need to provide

```
git add ../../../a/different/path/to/my/sourcecode/file_with_changes.foo
```

My question: Does git provide an easier way of specifying changed files?

E.g.:

```
git add file_with_changes.foo
```

Edit: The *testdata* directory contains furthermore config-files, which might be changed temporary, but should be excluded from the commit (possibly commited afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

```
git add .
```

will add all the changed files to the staging area.

or you can commit all the changed files directly without bothering about adding to the staging area by running the below command

```
git commit -a -m "<message>"
```

Please note that if the file to be committed is a new file then the above command will not commit it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: A good start. Thanks. Your answer however pointed out, that I did not completely specify my problem. (See edit of my question)...

Comment: Note that `git add .` will only add changes found in the current directory and recursively its subdirectories. If, as the OOP stated, you're several levels down a completely distinct branch of the tree, it isn't going to find stuff in the other branch...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Apart from `git add`ing directories (which recursively add all changes in the files contained in the directory), there is no shortcut.

On the other hand, many IDEs have some sort of git integration, which can help.  For example, in JetBrains' IDEs (IDEA, WebStorm, etc.), you can drag-n-drop files between changesets, or right-click to display a menu where you can add or remove the file from the index, etc.

Also, if you use bash, with git support for bash completion you can `git add TAB` and it should limit the tab completion to modified files.

You mentioned wanting to use the terminal... but I thought I'd mention that there are also several visual git front-ends that make it easier to add some files to the index.  I use SourceTree, which I find excellent, but it's available only for Windows and Mac.  There are others, though.

Comment: _git add [TAB]_ does not work for me. It results in the standard options for tab-completion: As _cd_ does, etc.

Comment: Do you have git bash completion installed/enabled?  If not, see http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks and try then.

Comment: I have it enabled, but it only allows me to complete git commands: git a[TAB][TAB] allows for command-completion: *add, am, annotate, ...*. But *git add* [TAB][TAB] does not allow for file-completion, which offers exclusively modified files.

Comment: Which version of git are you using? I'm on git 2.1.2, and using the git-completion.bash script in .../share/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash, which does complete to only modified files on `git add`.

Comment: It's possible that the git-completion.bash file was updated to include that somewhere between 1.7.9.5 and 2.1.2.  Maybe try using this file, see if that works. https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash  Keep a copy of your current one, in case it doesn't work.  (Or, if you can/want, update your git installation and try with the git-completion.bash that comes with it.)

Answer (score 0):

The shell-script below takes any string (allowing wildcards) as input argument. Any modified file within the git-repository matching this substring (also within its path) will be staged for commit.

To use it, copy the script to your *git-core*-directory (e.g. */usr/lib/git-core*) and assure that it is executeable:

```
sudo cp my-downloaded-git-script /usr/lib/git-core/git-add-by-substring && chmod 775 /usr/lib/git-core/git-add-by-substring
```

To have an overview over the effect of the script, you can optionally append a last line with

```
git status
```

**The script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: git add-by-substring \"substring to identify files\""
        echo "The script stages modified files, which contain the provided substring."
        exit
fi

substring=$1

list_of_files=$(git status | grep modified | sed 's/.*modified:   //' | grep ${substring})

if [ -z "$list_of_files" ]; then
        echo "No modified files, matching substring \"${substring}\""
        exit
fi

git add ${list_of_files}
```